# Rendering n number of grid items based in the dynamic column size

Tags: css-grid

I have a slider that ranges **from 1 and up to 3**. The slider's on change event sets the value of a CSS variable (e.g. `:root { --colNum: 1 }` ) so I am able to dynamically change the number of grid columns.

What I am trying to achieve is (let's say I have **six images in total**):

- When I have **one column** set, I would like to display only **the first image, full size** and **hide the five remaining images**.
- When I have **two columns** set, I would like to display the **first four images**, **two in each row** and **hide the two remaining images**.
- When I have **three columns** set, I would like to display **all the six images, three per row.**

Similar to the following images:

- **1 column and 1 image (1 row)** [image: 1 column]
- **2 columns and 4 images (2 rows)** [image: 2 columns]
- **3 columns and 6 images (2 rows)** [image: 3 columns]

I have created a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cjhy4w), tried different examples but none of them fit my needs so I have left it in an "initial state".

I am not sure if I am overthinking that but I am open to hear any suggestions or even other approaches in how I could achieve that result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change your `.image-item` to this: `.image-item{ height: 100%; width: 100%;}`

Comment: My main issue is with the quantity of images shown on the grid when I change the column's value using the slider. :/ Once I solve that I can think about the their sizes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But to achieve what you want, you'll need what I've told you regardless the number of items

Comment: Hi @dippas, I have just edited my question to be make more clear my aim. May you please check if what I need is possible to be done only using JS and CS ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally achieved what I wanted. Maybe it can help someone else facing similar case as mine.
The solution is going to be in the same [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cjhy4w) and I will be improving that to completely fit my needs.

#### Solution

In short, as I previously mentioned I have the CSS var (`--colNum`) changing its value dynamically based in the slider value.

I have filtered the items from the images array to conditionally render or not the images based in the `colNum` and image `index` values.

If I have a condition which renders the images I pass down a `style` props containing the `height` and `width` of the images and in cases it should not render I just return `null`.

Probably not the best approach but still.

```
const imagesByColumn = images.map((image, index) => {
    // One Image One Column
    if (colNum === '1') {
      if (index === 0) {
        const style = { width: '300px', height: '200px' };
        return <Image key={index} url={image.url} style={style} />;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    // Two Columns 4 Images
    if (colNum === '2') {
      if (index >= 0 && index < 4) {
        const style = { width: '170px', height: '120px' };
        return <Image key={index} url={image.url} style={style} />;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    // 3 Columns 6 Images
    if (colNum === '3') {
      const style = { width: '150px', height: '100px' };
      return <Image key={index} url={image.url} style={style} />;
    }

    return null;
  });
```